How to disable Recaptcha in REST APIs?
I am using magento 2.4.7 but when i enable repaptcha it works fine on the website but in APIs it gives me an error
"message": "ReCaptcha validation failed, please try again",

I want to enable Recatcha only on webiste not on Mobile App / APIs ?
How can i do that please help

You need to be add the integration token into the header.
I replicate this error on my postman on the customer login api.

Before adding integration token it give us ReCaptcha validation failed.
After setting the integration token into the headers, it's generate the
customer token.


Thanks, But what if i want it on edit account api there i need customer token to update account !!

It still giving the same error

Can you double check your integration token is correct ?

Yes these are correct !!

Can you share your postman collection request once ?
Also Signature method would be HMAC-SHA256
Add authorization data to - Request Headers

I added it in the answer please re check

Add authorization data to - Request Headers : Please correct this option https://prnt.sc/aDOWWOBuBB3S

Thanks Its working but is there any alternative to bypass recaptcha in apis ?

what is consumer key and consumer secret ??

You will get from Admin -> System -> Integrations

yes still get same error

check the above comment " Request Headers : Please correct this option prnt.sc/aDOWWOBuBB3S"
